# Struts 1.3 getting dynamically created values to backend for validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, struts, struts-1

I am using struts 1.3. 
I have a jsp page with a question and set of answers.
A code fragment is given below.

```
<c:forEach items="${TestForm.testQuestions}" var="var" 
           varStatus="status" step="1" begin="0">
    <tr class="row"> 
        <td>
            <c:out value="${var.question}" />
            <input type="hidden" value="<c:out value="var.qId"/>" 
                   id="qstnId${status.index}">
        </td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="A" name="opt${status.index}">A</td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="B" name="opt${status.index}">B</td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="C" name="opt${status.index}">C</td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="D" name="opt${status.index}">D</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Is there any way I can get the `questionid` (`qstnId${status.index}`) and selected `value`, store it in a formbean and validate in back end?

Comment: You need to retitle the question.  It has nothing to do with getting the width of an element.

Answer (score 1):

@Arun Raj Checkout this code. I am just extending Karna's Code.

```
// Get name
var name = $("input[type='radio']:checked").attr("name");  
// Remove non-digit characets
var index = name.replace(/\D/g,'');

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "Ur_Servlet_URL",
data: { name: name,index: index }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
 //If you need anything to return.
});
```

You can receive the values in servlet like this.

```
String name=request.getParameter("name");
String index=request.getParameter("index");
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get name
var name = $("input[type='radio']:checked").attr("name");  
// Remove non-digit characets
var index = name.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

Comment: i need to get those to the backend java servlet for validation